# How to replace css('background-image')

Tags: javascript, css, background-image

I want to replace css('background-image') path.

The problem:

for the same variable `oldBgImg = this.element.css('background-image')`

FireFox returns -

```
"url("http://mySite/images/file1.png")"
```

but Chrome returns it **without the quotes**:

```
"url(http://mySite/images/file1.png)"
```

Here is the solution I use. can you please help me make it simpler?

```
var oldBgImg = this.element.css('background-image');    
// => FF:   "url("http://mySite/images/file1.png")"
// Chrome:  "url(http://mySite/images/file1.png)"
//   According to http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-uri :
//   quotes are optional, so Chrome does not use them, but FF does . . .

var n1 = oldBgImg.lastIndexOf("(");  n1 += 1;  // now points to the char after the "("
var n2 = oldBgImg.lastIndexOf(")");  n2 -= 1;  // now points to the char before the ")"
var c1 = oldBgImg.substring(n1, n1 + 1);       // test the first Char after the "("
var c2 = oldBgImg.substring(n2, n2 + 1);       // test the first Char after the "("
if ( (c1 == "\"") || (c1 == "\'") ) { n1 += 1; }
if ( (c2 == "\"") || (c2 == "\'") ) { n2 -= 1; }
var oldBgImgPath = oldBgImg.substring(n1, n2 + 1);       // [ (" ] .. [ ") ]
var n = oldBgImgPath.lastIndexOf("/");
var newBgImgPath = oldBgImgPath.substring(0, n + 1) + "file2.gif";

// if needed, should also add : 
//    var path = encodeURI(newBgImgPath);
this.element.css('background-image', 'url(' + newBgImgPath + ')');
```

Notes:

1. According to http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-uri
   one can use single quote or double-quote or no quote sign
2. I am looking for a general solution, also for relative path (without "http" or with "file") , I just want to replace the fileName within the URL.

Comment: Could be easier to do with regular expressions?

Comment: as i know you can use both quoted and and unquoted url in ff. try changing it and see what happens!

Comment: @Homan - I know. the problem is that I try to change a value that is taken form the CSS initial file, and each browser treat its differently - with or without quotes . . .

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to do it with regular expressions. - [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/phr2il7Jih)

The expression:

```
("?)(http:.*?)\1\)
```

The match

```
url = 'url("http://mySite/images/file1.png")'.match(/("?)(http:.*?)\1\)/)[2];
```

You can then reconstruct your property.

```
$(this).css( 'background-image', 'url("' + url + "')" );
```

This should work on all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I did it with regular expressions. I use this code:

```
var re = /url\(['"]?(.+?)[^\/]+['"]?\)/;
var regs = re.exec(oldBgImg);
var newBgImgPath = regs[1] + "file2.png";
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VGLGR/1/)**

I'll explain the RE.

1. It starts with a `/`, this will indicate it's a RE.
2. Then there's `url\(`. It matches the text `url(`. `(` is escaped because it is a reserved character.
3. Then there is `['"]?`. `['"]` matches `'` or `"` and the `?` makes it optional.
4. A `(` starts a RE group, that can be referred to.
5. In `.+?` `.` matches all charaters except a newline. A `+` tells that there must be at least 1 of them, or more. Finally, a `?` makes the `+` non-greedy, so it matches as little characters as possible but still tries to match the whole RE.
6. A `)` ends the group.
7. `[^\/]` matches any non-`/` character. Then there's a `+` again. It has no `?` after it, because we want to match as many non-`/`  characters (the file name) from the end as we can.
8. Finally, another optional quote, an escaped `)` for the closing bracket in `url(...)` and a `/` to end the RE.

Now `re.exec(oldBgImg)` returns an array with the first element being the whole matched string and the next elements being the matched RE groups (created by `()` brackets). Then I can just take `regs[1]`, which is the first matched *group* and contains the pathname.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. but what if I have a single quote? what if the URL does not start with "http" ? I am looking for a more general solution.

Comment: @Atara Edited RE to match single quotes; already works with URLs not starting with "http". It just returns the URL between `url(` and `)` without anything after the last `/`.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the quotes in `oldBgImg` with nothing like this.

```
oldBgImg = oldBgImg.replace(/\"/g, "");
```

That way the URL is always the same no matter what browser retrieved it.